# Ctrlp find in project

Tags: vim, ctrlp

So after adding this to CtrlP, I know how a fast file searcher.

```
let g:ctrlp_user_command = 'ag %s -i --nocolor --nogroup --hidden
    \ --ignore .git
    \ --ignore .svn
    \ --ignore .hg
    \ --ignore .DS_Store
    \ --ignore "**/*.pyc"
    \ -g ""'
let g:ctrlp_use_caching = 0
let g:ctrlp_working_path_mode = 0
let g:ctrlp_switch_buffer = 0
let g:ctrlp_extensions = ['buffertag', 'tag', 'line', 'dir']
let g:ctrlp_match_func = {'match' : 'matcher#cmatch' }
```

But one thing I'm trying to achieve is being able to search an entire project for any random string. The `line` extension lets me search the current file, but I'd like that functionality without having to open anything.

Essentially, `grep` but inside the ctrlp buffer. Is this possible or would I need to make an extension for this?

Comment: http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/3176/46

Comment: I think somewhere along the lines of [helm-ag](https://github.com/syohex/emacs-helm-ag) for emacs

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at [The-Silver-Searcher](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) vim extension? It wouldn't be in your ctrlp, but it's kinda like grep from inside vim, and you can open the file by selecting it from the search results. To search for some string in your project you can type something like:

`:Ag 'string' ./`

then navigate to the file you like and push enter. You can use most of the grep options like `-i` for ignore case or `-v` for invert match.